# Срезанные углы блока

Tags: html, css, svg

Нужно срезать углы блока так, чтобы фон срезанных частей был прозрачным. Фон будет изображением, так что треугольники не подойдут. При этом нужно, чтобы у всего блока со срезанной частью была рамка, и потому тут проблема.

Я создал срез с помощью `clip-path`, но рамка блока срезается так же, как и он сам. В итоге выходит так:

[image: пример]

```css
html,
body,
.bdiv,
.mainblock {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bdiv {
    display: table;
}
.mainblock {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainblock>div {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: ddd;
}
.head-text {
    clip-path: polygon(460px 0, 100% 30px, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #eee;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    background: #333;
}
.cont-text {
    background: #000;
}
.cont-text>form input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style="background: #444;">
<div class="bdiv">

 <div class="mainblock">
  <div>
   <div class="content head-text">Приветствую!</div>
   <div class="content cont-text">
    <form>
     <input type="button" value="Привет">
     <input type="button" value="Пока">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Можно, конечно, добавить абсолютный блок-линию как рамку поверх среза, но по-моему так не делается. Но как тогда? Мне нужно 2 таких среза, один как на картинке, а второй слева внизу.

Comment: Обычно полигон-бордеры делают с помощью вложенного блока с таким же clip-path: http://codepen.io/bennettfeely/full/azJWWX/ У внутреннего даже можно писать `clip-path:inherit`

Comment: @vp_arth в вашем примере есть 2 полигона, один чуть больше, другой чуть меньше, таким образом выходит рамка. Выглядит странновато, но если других вариантов не будет попробую реализовать так.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
html,
body,
.bdiv,
.mainblock {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bdiv {
    display: table;
}
.mainblock {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainblock>div {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    /* background: #444; */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ddd;
}

.head-text {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 30px, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 15px);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 30px, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 15px);
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #eee;    
    background: url(https://www.noupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/pattern-13.jpg) center no-repeat;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 30px, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 25px);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 30px, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 25px);
    padding: 5px;
} 

.cont-text {
    background: #000;
}
.cont-text>form input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 40%;
}

body {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="bdiv">
  <div class="mainblock"> 
    <div>
      <div class="box"><div class="content head-text">Приветствую!</div></div>
      <div class="content cont-text">
        <form>
          <input type="button" value="Привет">
          <input type="button" value="Пока">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В плане так и я могу :) Мне нужно что бы рамка шла по срезу, а не как тут. Типа косая рамка. (второй срез должен был быть на блоке внизу, но это не важно)

Comment: Даже больше, пожалуй выберу ваш вариант, так как фон шапки ожидается сделать гифкой или с помощью видео, а с SVG будет много проблем это сделать.

Comment: @Telion никаких проблем с шапкой, выполненной на SVG.  Получается настоящая адаптивная страничка. Даже анимация добавленная на эту страничку будет масштабироваться на лету и работать при этом. Попробуйте вот эту страничку подвигать - https://svg-art.ru/  Если немного подождете, я сюда доделаю свой вариант вашего задания.

Comment: @Telion, а можно узнать, чем этот "качественный" вариант отличается от первоначально предложенного мной "странноватого"?

Comment: @vp_arth я поставил вам плюс тоже за вариант, но этот человек доделал ваш вариант подстроив его под мои нужды.

Comment: @Alexandr_T погодите ка. Как поставить в варианте Elena фон картинкой или видео? В самом примере показано что картинка добавлена через svg, другой медиаконтент так добавить нельзя, или как?

Comment: @Telion я имел ввиду, что и анимация будет сделана на SVG, только в  этом случае её можно будет масштабировать и она будет продолжать работать. Я не говорил, что у вас вся страничка будет сделана на SVG, только будут вставки в Html страничку, ну и другой медиаконтент добавляйте стандартными путями. Я разместил свой вариант решения, смотрите

Answer (score 7):

Такой вот еще вариант svg:

```css
html,
body,
.bdiv,
.mainblock {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bdiv {
    display: table;
}
.mainblock {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainblock>div {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: ddd;
}
.head-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 15px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.cont-text {
    background: #000;
}
.cont-text>form input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 40%;
}


.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.top-bg {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: #444;">
<div class="bdiv">

 <div class="mainblock">
  <div>
   <div class="top">
              <svg width="500" height="50" class="top-bg" viewBox="0 0 500 50">
                <defs>
                  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="850" height="315">
                    <image xlink:href="http://www.wallpapersonview.com/wallpapers/2/fbcover_facebook_timeline_black_amazing_high_quality_desktop_background-011.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="850" height="315" />
                  </pattern>
                </defs>

                <path stroke="#fff" fill="url(#img1)" stroke-width="5" 
                      d="M 2,2 L 450,2 L 498,20 L 498,48 L 50,48 L 2,30 z"/>
              </svg>
              
     <div class="content head-text">Приветствую!</div>
   </div>
   <div class="content cont-text">
    <form>
     <input type="button" value="Привет">
     <input type="button" value="Пока">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Telion В данном примере без разницы, так как `<polygon>` рисует только прямыми отрезками, но <path> более мощный и гибкий инструмент.  Для реализации пути у <path> есть много форматов записи. Кстати и такой  то же  - `<path d="M80,0 100,20 100,100 20,100 0,80 0,0" style="stroke:purple;stroke-width:1"/>`

Comment: Поддерживаю, без разницы

Answer (score 6):

### SVG - решение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<style>
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

.bdiv {
    display: table;
}
.container {
position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

</style>
<html>
<body>

<div class="bdiv"> 
<div class="container"> 

<svg version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="460" height="100" viewBox="0 0 460 100" style="border:0px solid red">
    <defs>
   <mask id="rect1">
   <g fill="white">
   <path id="p1" d="M56,40 30,25 30,10 404,10 430,25 430,40z "  />
    <path id="p2" d="M82,80 56,65 56,50 204,50 256,80z" /> 
    <path id="p3" d="M270,80 218,50 399,50 430,65 430,80z"/>
       </g>  
  </mask>
 </defs>
 <style>
   #p2:hover, #p3:hover{
   fill:orangered;
   color:white;
   }
</style>
         <rect  width="460" height="100" fill-opacity="0.3"  fill="black" /> 
        <rect  width="460" height="100" fill-opacity="0.1"  fill="black"  mask="url(#rect1)"/>  
   <g  stroke-width="2" stroke="white" stroke-opacity="0.5"      fill="none">    
      <path id="p1" d="M56,40 30,25 30,10 404,10 430,25 430,40 56,40z" />
      <path id="p2" d="M82,80 56,65 56,50 204,50 256,80z" />
      <path id="p3"  d="M270,80 218,50 399,50 430,65 430,80z" /> 
         </g>
   <g font-size="0.9em" font-family="verdana"  stroke="white" fill="white">  
    <text id="txt1" x="170" y="28" > Приветствую!  </text>
     <text id="txt2" x="120" y="70" > Привет  </text> 
     <text  id="txt3" x="320" y="70" > Пока  </text>   
      </g> 
 </svg> 
</div> 
</div>

</body>
```

Здесь три кнопки меню выполнены с помощью трех патчей. Эти же патчи входят в маску, которая служит для того, чтобы стал виден фон.

Решение универсальное, так как не нужно будет подбирать каждый раз окраску кнопок и их обводку. Она всегда будет гармонировать с выбранным фоном страницы.  Для проверки замените фон или откройте сниппет на полный просмотр.

Попробуйте заменить фон на другую картинку. На кнопки я сделал ховер, в принципе нетрудно добавить к ним ссылки. Все элементы в одном блоке SVG. Его лучше добавить в Html страничку инлайн.

### Update 23.08.2017

Доработка примера по замечаниям в комментариях автора вопроса

> При наведении на текст ссылка теряет фон до тех пор пока курсор не
>   выйдет за пределы блока и обратно. И я все так и не понял как сделать
>   анимированный фон определенному блоку SVG

Данный эффект происходил из-за того, что текст в блоках не входил в
    группу, для которой был применен селектор `:hover`.  Решил эту
    проблему объединением блока и текста в одну группу.

```
<g id="p2">
                 <path  d="M82,80 56,65 56,50 204,50 256,80z" />
                  <text id="txt2" x="120" y="70" font-size="0.9em" font-
                  family="verdana" fill="white" > Привет  </text>
 </g>
```

Добавлена анимация фона и текста при помощи изменения прозрачности

```
#p1:hover, #p2:hover, #p3:hover{
   fill:dodgerblue;
   color:white;
   opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;

   }
   #p1, #p2, #p3
   {
    opacity:0.5;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
       transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   }
```

Ниже, доработанный пример:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/22/06/1e/22061e28e591fb82b41a151d64cefe55.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

.bdiv {
    display: table;
}
.container {
position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
#p1:hover, #p2:hover, #p3:hover{
   fill:dodgerblue;
   color:white;
   opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
 
   }
   #p1, #p2, #p3
   {
    opacity:0.5;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
       transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="bdiv"> 
<div class="container"> 

<svg version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="460" height="100" viewBox="0 0 460 100" style="border:0px solid red">
    <defs>
   <mask id="rect1">
   <g fill="white">
   <path  d="M56,40 30,25 30,10 404,10 430,25 430,40z "  />
    <path  d="M82,80 56,65 56,50 204,50 256,80z" /> 
    <path  d="M270,80 218,50 399,50 430,65 430,80z"/>
       </g>  
  </mask>
 </defs>

         <rect  width="460" height="100" fill-opacity="0.3"  fill="black" /> 
        <rect  width="460" height="100" fill-opacity="0.1"  fill="black"  mask="url(#rect1)"/>  
   <g  stroke="white"    fill="none">    
      <g id="p1">
        <path  d="M56,40 30,25 30,10 404,10 430,25 430,40 56,40z" />
     <text id="txt1" x="170" y="28" font-size="0.9em" font-family="verdana" fill="white" > Приветствую!  </text>
      </g>
      <g id="p2">
        <path  d="M82,80 56,65 56,50 204,50 256,80z" />
      <text id="txt2" x="120" y="70" font-size="0.9em" font-family="verdana" fill="white" > Привет  </text>
      </g>
      <g id="p3">
         <path   d="M270,80 218,50 399,50 430,65 430,80z" /> 
         <text  id="txt3" x="320" y="70"font-size="0.9em" font-family="verdana" fill="white" > Пока  </text>   
      </g>
         </g>
  
    
  
  
      </g> 
 </svg> 
</div> 
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит шикарно, примерно как я хотел сделать. Но тут 2 проблемы. При наведении на текст ссылка теряет фон до тех пор пока курсор не выйдет за пределы блока и обратно. И я все так и не понял как сделать анимированный фон определенному блоку SVG. (прошу прощения, я ввел вас в заблуждение, как сделать картинку я понял, вопрос в анимации. Например при наведении на кнопку ее фон становится не цвета или картинки, а определенная анимация, возможно я буду даже использовать библиотеки для анимации спрайтов, но они обычно под canvas)

Comment: @Telion спасибо за оценку. Но в задании не шла речь о ссылках и анимации фона, это уже другой вопрос. У меня предложение - оформите новый вопрос и тщательно сформулируйте своё задание. Не просто на словах, а желательно  с картинками поясняющими суть. Ну как вы сделали в этом изначально вопросе:)  Ведь анимацию фона кнопок или чего-то ещё, можно сделать очень многими способами. Я уверен, что многие откликнутся.

Comment: @Telion Ваши замечания учтены, смотрите второй пример, после **Update 23.08.2017**

Answer (score 3):

Решение с вложенным дивом с таким же `clip-path`:

```css
.content {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: ddd;
}
.head-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #eee;
  background: #333;
}
.inborder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; left: 5px;
  clip-path: inherit;
}
.border {
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(
    95% 0, 
    100% 45%, 
    100% 100%, 
    5% 100%,
    0 55%, 
    0 0
  );
  background: red;
  min-height: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="inborder content head-text">
    Приветствую!
  </div>
</div>
```