# Верстка резанных углов

Tags: css

Нужно сверстать резанный угол.Каким образом можно это реализовать?
Сразу скажу линейный градиент не подходит.

https://prnt.sc/nsud5r
[image]

Comment: https://rusatov.github.io/Cat_Food/dist/  вот так

Comment: @MaximLensky гы опять кот, Вам везет на него =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я же говорил ...ещё будут этот вопрос плодить ..вопрос закрыть

Comment: @MaximLensky, ну так в ответы, не?

Comment: Я этот вопрос видел уже минимум раза три, где-то должно быть возможно отметить как дубликат

Comment: Я задавал сей вопрос давным давно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644310/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уважаемый автор всё же поясню что на нативном css это делается именно на градиенте 
нам потребуется два блока первый и второй это который белый на котором мы расположим кота и все предложения

Вот здесь можете потренироваться: [codepen.io/pen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/byvPje?editors=1100)

В общем имеем блок с градиентом  **linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, #000 0);**

> где ключевой момент именно 135deg + transparent 30px

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(http://izhevsk.ru/forums/icons/forum_pictures/009986/9986516.jpg);
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 220px;
  height: 340px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, #000 0);
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, #fff 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="items">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-a">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-a">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-a">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```