# Как сделать фаску на div блоке?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать фаску на div блоке, с сохранением border и фона.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

div {
  width: 320px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ff7f27;
}

div:hover {
  border: 4px solid #d91667;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985313/308951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

div {
  width: 320px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-left:none;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background: #ff7f27;
  margin-left:50px;
  position: absolute;

}

div:after {
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: 40px;
  transform: translate(-100%,40px);
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background: #ff7f27;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  height: 62px;
  width: 62px;
  transform: translate(-29.5px,9px)rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  background: #ff7f27;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

div:hover, div:hover:before, div:hover:after {
  border-color:  #d91667!important;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```